# prepared statement values not binding

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to bind parameters in a prepared sql statement, and am not able to do so. The code I have is:

```
function accountGet($database,$target,$index,$index_value) {
    $sql = 'SELECT :target from accounts WHERE :index = :index_value';
    $query = $database->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(
        ':target' => $target,
        ':index' => $index,
        ':index_value' => $index_value
    ));
    print_r($query);
}
```

The parameters don't seem to be binding. I am getting a statement returned: `PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT :target from accounts WHERE :index = :index_value )` How do I fix this?

Comment: Simple, you can't bind columns from a SELECT. `SELECT :target` <= uh-huh.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks. I changed it to `$sql = 'SELECT '.$target.' from accounts WHERE :index = :index_value';` and that works, but `:index` and `index_value` still do not bind

Comment: You're welcome. That's because `index` is a reserved MySQL word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html most likely the reason. Try and choose another name for it. Plus, am not sure if you can do `WHERE :index`

Comment: I'm assuming you just can't bind values to columns.

Comment: Rule of thumb: would the query work if you replaced the placeholder with a literal string `'hello'` or number `42`? If not, then you cannot use a placeholder there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding columns is not going to work you're going to have to build the string directly:

```
   function accountGet($database,$target,$index,$index_value) {
        $sql = "SELECT `$target` from accounts WHERE `$index` = :index_value";
        $query = $database->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':index_value' => $index_value));
        print_r($query);    
        //$result = $query->fetchAll();     
        //print_r($result);
    }
```